# Reference Initialized Dictionary In Other Modules | Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, vba6

I am somewhat new to the VBA arena (currently deal more with Python & Bash), but am attempting to utilize an initialized dictionary for applications across other modules. Consider the following dictionary construction contained inside a Sub, executed on ThisWorkbook.Open:

```
Public dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim events As Variant, haztype As Variant, amount As Variant
  events = Array("1", "2", "3") 
  haztype = Array ("Heavy Snow", "Blizzard", "Snow Squalls")
  amount = Array("16", "36", "3")
  For step = LBound(events) To UBound(events)
    dict.Add events(step), Array(haztype(step), amount(step))
  Next step
End Sub
```

If I were to add a simpler loop function inside this Sub to print the dictionary's keys and corresponding values, I find it's been populated correctly.

My issue is accessing this dictionary's keys and values elsewhere. For example, I've attempted to access this dictionary in a module and function to print out values, which was done in the following manner:

```
Sub HelpItsSnowing()
  Dim key As Variant
  For Each key in dict.Keys
    MsgBox prompt:="" & dict.item(key)(0) & " | " & dict.item(key)(1) & " | " & dict.item(key)(2) & ""
  Next key
End Sub
```

When I go to execute this, I receive the following error:

> Runtime 424 Error: Object Required

Microsoft Scripting Runtime has been toggled on in the Tools menu. I've also tried using Option Explicit at both ThisWorkbook.Open and the downstream module HelpItsSnowing, which returns the following error in the downstream module:

> Compile Error: Variable Not Defined

Any help with this seemingly odd error would be appreciated!

Comment: Move `Public dict As Scripting.Dictionary` to a regular module. Also it would be better not to name your modules the same as your subroutines or functions.

Comment: ...or if it's in the `ThisWorkbook` module you'd need to use `ThisWorkbook.dict` to reference it.

Comment: @TimWilliams this is exactly where the referenced post up top landed me. To clarify, the dictionary reference would look like `ThisWorkbook.dict`, would I need to also declare this dictionary at the top of a module it would be used in?

Comment: Variables only need to be declared once - you don't need to re-declare anywhere else.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility